# Spring Integration DSL Channel Support

Tags: spring-integration, spring-dsl

In the current release 1.0.2 of spring integration dsl I can see some of the basic channels are not present like ReST/HTTP, TCP/UDP, JDBC, MQTT, etc.

Just wanted to know whether this protocols/channel are in roadmap or it has been excluded deliberately.

PS: I might be sounding stupid with posted question but just wanted to know the reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From one side you should understand that it is enough big work to address them all. For example [HTTP module](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INTEXT-185) is on our radar for the `1.1` release.

From other side the Spring Integration Java DSL is just an edition to the existing Spring Java & Annotation configuration, so any `@Bean` definition is valid there, too.

With those desired protocols you can go ahead and configure their components as `@Bean` and refer them from the `.handle()` or `.from()` EIP-methods.

For example:

```
@Bean
public MessageSource<Object> jdbcMessageSource() {
    return new JdbcPollingChannelAdapter(this.dataSource, "SELECT * FROM foo");
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow myFlow() {
   return IntegrationFlows.from(jdbcMessageSource())
                        .split(...)
                        .transform(...)
                        .handle(new MqttPahoMessageHandler("tcp://localhost:1883", "si-test-out"))
                        .get();
}
```